# Eclipse RCP table dynamic update

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I want to make a table in a view part which will be dynamically updated (row count, column count, column name). The model is a collection of string array. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be to use a TableViewer instance, specify its content provider and then, you can call its refresh() method every time a change has been made to its content.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet of code? Because it is hard to find something useful. I have read about TableViewer. Still can you exlain my task in a simple example. Thx in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html

Comment: I saw this one, but it does not explain one thing. How I can change column name and number?

Comment: If you want to change column name, simply work retrieve the Column from the TableViewerColumn instance and call setName(). If you want to add columns, create a new TableViewerColumn instance. That's it

Answer (score 0):

@itun. Simplest way to show columns dynamically is to create all columns and set the width of unnecessary columns to zero.
There is another way (which I am using) to create dynamic columns is as follow.

1. Create Extension Point for columns (column name,orientation,data provider)
2. Create Extension of by using step 1.
3. Implementation of creating columns in View.

   ```
       String[] id = preferences.getString(PREFS_COLUMNS).split(";");
       for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
           String name = "";
           int style = SWT.LEFT;
           Image image = null;
           ILabelProvider provider = registry.createLabelProvider(id[i]);
           if (provider != null) {
               name = registry.getName(id[i]);
               style = registry.getOrientation(id[i]);
               if (provider instanceof ITableLabelProvider) {
                   name = ((ITableLabelProvider) provider).getColumnText(null, i);
                   image = ((ITableLabelProvider) provider).getColumnImage(null, i);
               }
           } else {
               LogFactory.getLog(getClass()).warn("Missing column [" + id[i] + "]");
           }
           if (index < table.getColumnCount()) {
               tableColumn = table.getColumn(index);
               if (tableColumn.getData("labelProvider") != null)
                   ((ILabelProvider) tableColumn.getData("labelProvider")).dispose();
           } else {
               tableColumn = new TableColumn(table, style);
               tableColumn.addControlListener(columnControlListener);
               tableColumn.addSelectionListener(columnSelectionListener);
               tableColumn.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
                   public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                       if (e.widget.getData("labelProvider") != null)
                           ((ILabelProvider) e.widget.getData("labelProvider")).dispose();
                   }
               });
           }
           tableColumn.setText(name);
           tableColumn.setAlignment(style);
           tableColumn.setImage(image);
           tableColumn.setMoveable(true);
           tableColumn.setData("labelProvider", provider);
           tableColumn.setData("columnId", id[i]);
           index++;
       }
   ```